# Can you track video events like play, stop, and finished with Classic Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm new with the event tracking services offered by Google Analytics. I was just wondering if you could track video events using classic analytics or did you need to implement Universal Analytics? Plus what code would you use to implement this kind of event tracking? Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: Which video provider are you using? Each will have a different implementation?

Comment: Primarily vimeo and youtube

Answer (score 0):

Each video provider (in your case Youtube/Vimeo) will have very different API callbacks so you'll need to include some JavaScript on your webpages to pick up the API callbacks when certain events are triggered (i.e. video played, video paused, video complete etc) and fire Analytics events.

I've used both of these in the past and they both provide the functionality you're looking for, they'll trigger events in your Google Analytics and should be compatible with Classic Analytics, Universal Analytics and Google Tag Manager:

- Vimeo - http://www.sanderheilbron.nl/vimeo.ga.js/
- Youtube - http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/05/11/updated-youtube-tracking-google-analytics-gtm/

Comment: Thank you so much! This is extremely helpful. Just one other question would I need this for basic events like tracking how many times a button is pressed?

Comment: If it's for buttons within the video window then yes unfortunately. The reason being you have little/no control over the rendering of the video player and there will likely be multiple methods of playing/pausing a video for example (i.e. space bar will often pause a video but no click is necessary).

Comment: Oh okay that's good to know. One more thing how would you go about firing the event in analytics?